# Using functions in Maple

Tags: functions, maple

How do approach this problem?

Write a function points which takes a list L of non negative integers and returns a list of pairs $[x, y]$ where $1 ≤ x ≤$ the length of $L$ and $1 ≤ y ≤ L[x]$.

Comment: Why ask in a math forum instead of in a programming forum?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done as a nested loop, ie. one loop within another, where the one or both of the end-points of the inner loop will depend upon the current value of the outer loop.

You can use a pair of for-do loops, but then you have to be creative about where to store the list [x,y] that gets generated each time through the inner loop (or be inefficient in memory and repeatedly concatenate with a list of previous pairs). It's easier and efficient to accumulate instead an expression sequence of all the [x,y] pairs using a pair of nested calls to the `seq` command rather than a pair of for-do loops.

The inner loop can determine `y`, since that loop has to run from 1 to `L[x]` where a particular `x` would be known. The outer loop can determine `x`, since the restrictions on `x` don't involve `y`.

The length of a list `L` is obtained with the command `nops(L)`.

Experiment with a pair of nested `seq` calls like the following, to get an idea of how they can form a longer sequence of results. Your goal is to nest such a pair in the right order and to find the particular ranges `i=a..b` and `j=c..d` where some of the `a,b,c,d` of the inner `seq` may depend upon `i` or `j` of the outer `seq`.

```
seq( seq( [i,j], i=4..j ), j=1..6 );
```

Notice that if the right end-point of a range is less that the left end-point then that range is empty: it produces nothing. This comes in handy. For example, the following produces `NULL`.

```
seq( i, i=4..2 );
```